# Теряется первое нажатие на клавишу

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Дистрибутив Ubuntu 18.04
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.15.0-48-generic

Последние 2 недели при начале ввода стали пропадать первые буквы текста.
К примеру, если пытаюсь ввести в терминале 'apt get update', то по итогу получается 'pt get update'.
Особенность в том, что фокус на текстовом поле есть всегда. И нет разницы, окно терминала,текстовые поля браузера или ide.

До этого, как и у большинства пользователей ubuntu на gnome была проблема с отображением текущей раскладки в top bar.
И, на сколько мне не изменяет память, данная проблема с потерей символа началась как раз таки после фикса этой проблема.

Что можете посоветовать в поисках причины?

UPD: т.к. во время проблемы клавиатуры была вставлена в USB хаб, расположенный в мониторе, тот в свою очередь через USB B(монитор) к компьютеру(USB A). Решил переподключить клаву напрямую к компьютеру. С тех пор, проблем не наблюдалось. Тут 2 варианта, либо пофиксили в системе, либо проблема в usb хабе.
Если рассмотреть проблема хаба, то логически предположить, что раз терялось нажатие клавиатуры, то также должно было теряться и нажатие мыши, чего небыло.

Больше склоняюсь к идее, что проблема в USB хабе.

Comment: Не может ли быть проблемы в клавиатуре? Втыкание вместо неё другой что-нибудь меняет?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev, 3 клавиатуры протестировал. Так же клавиатуруку с PS\2 разъём. Аналогично

Answer (score 0):

Да, это проблема в USB хабе на мониторе. Было такое же, с прямым подключением к ноуту проблемa ушла. С USB 4 порта мини хабом подключенным к ноуту - никаких проблем.

Comment: Вероятно, проблема не хаба, а системы, которая отправляет хаб в сон, за долгое бездействие.

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема, usb-клавиатура подключена через usb-хаб.
Подключена была к второму usb-разъему на хабе, первый не использовался.
Подключил клавиатуру на первый usb-разъем, проблема исчезла.